# Upper semi-continuity results

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, continuity

I have recently been introduced to the notion of **upper semi-continuity** on a metric space $X$. Please advise on the following queries:

- If $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is upper semi-continuous and $y_{n} \rightarrow y$ in $X$, does it follow that $$\limsup\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(y_{n}) \leq f(y)?$$
- If $f:X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is upper semi-continuous then is $U = \{ x \in X: f(x) \leq g(x)\}$ open? $g$ is mapping from $X$ to $\mathbb{R}$ ?

For the second question I am aware of the characterization that $f$ is upper semi-continuous iff for any $c \in \mathbb{R}$, $f^{-1}((-\infty,c))$ is open but in the case I mentioned $g(x)$ is not necessarily constant.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: it would be $f(x) < g(x)$ anyway!

Answer (score 0):

First question: yes.

Second: That wouldn't even work, if $f$ is continuous. Think $f$ as a constant function and $g$ discontinuous.